# adding animate to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I Tried many codes but i dint get the proper output which am expecting, need to add the animate class to the following code in jQuery. am the beginner to jQuery

http://7revolution.com/captain/captain/empty.php

```js
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    //Enable sidebar toggle
    $("[data-toggle='offcanvas']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //If window is small enough, enable sidebar push menu
        if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active', 1000);
            $('.left-side').removeClass("collapse-left", 1000);
            $(".right-side").removeClass("strech", 1000);
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass("relative", 1000);
        } else {
            //Else, enable content streching
            $('.left-side').toggleClass("collapse-left", 1000);
            $(".right-side").toggleClass("strech", 1000);
        }
    });
```

```css
right-side, .left-side {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*right side - contins main content*/
.right-side {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  margin-left: 220px;
}
/*left side - contains sidebar*/
.left-side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  top: 0;
}

.left-side.collapse-left {
  left: -220px;
}


.right-side.strech {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.right-side.strech > .content-header {
  margin-top: 0px;
}



.row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {
  right: -220px;
}
.row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
  left: -220px;
}
.row-offcanvas-right.active {
  right: 220px;
}
.row-offcanvas-left.active {
  left: 220px;
}

body.fixed .row-offcanvas-left.active .navbar {
  left: 220px !important;
  right: 0;
}
body.fixed .row-offcanvas-left.active .sidebar-offcanvas {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <i class="el-icon-braille"></i>
                </a>

    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">   
      <br/><br/> <!-- only to run perfectly in stackoverflow.com -->
      some left side content
      </aside>
<aside class="right-side">   
some right side content
</aside>
```

Comment: Ok, what were you expecting?

Comment: info is not complete

Answer (score 0):

Well worth checking to see if you can achieve what you're after with CSS tansitions. Most of the problems with kind of thing have to do with not organising your classes properly and with certain problems to do with unit conversion (i.e. colour: red to any rgba value).
Also, consider @media CSS query for your window.width classes:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
   //wider screen styles here
}

@media (max-width: 991px){
   //narrower screen styles
}
```

Hard to know with any class info, but have a look at a broken jquery toggleClass example [here](http://codepen.io/esparragito/pen/hgHoI)
Please note that I wouldn't recommend using an #id selector here, I only show it as an example of a potential source of problems!

CSS

```
#button {
  width: 300px;/*#id selector more specific needs to be explicitly overridden by the toggled class.*/
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(122,122,122, 0.4);
}

.clicked {
  width: 10em; /*change this to !important to see the correct change*/
  height: 20em !important; /*  unit conversion OK */
  background-color: red; /* unit conversion not OK */
}
```

and the JS

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked', 1000);
});
```